# C++ How to cout a vector of struts, EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: c++, xcode, vector

Can someone help me with this error. I've been up all night trying to get this code to work, can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to COUT a single value from my vector strut but I keep getting this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I used breaks to see if variables are as they should be and they are but the error continues. Can you help me?

```
        vector<department> depart;
        depart.push_back(department());

        while(lineNum <= lineCount)  
        {
            lineNum = lineNum;
            depart[lineNum].dept = sTemp1;
            depart[lineNum].building = sTemp2;
            depart[lineNum].budget = sTempToInt;
            depart.push_back(department());  
            lineNum++;
        }
        vector<department> deptVec;
        cout << "Vector output: " << deptVec[0].budget;
    }
        else
        {
            sTemp1.erase (remove (sTemp1.begin(), sTemp1.end(), ' '), sTemp1.end()); //clean up
            //sTemp2.erase (remove (sTemp2.begin(), sTemp2.end(), ' '), sTemp2.end()); //clean up
            sTemp2.erase(find_if(sTemp2.rbegin(), sTemp2.rend(), bind1st(std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ')).base(), sTemp2.end());
            sTemp3.erase (remove (sTemp3.begin(), sTemp3.end(), ' '), sTemp3.end()); //clean up
            sTempToInt = stoi(sTemp1);//file is instructor

            vector<intructor> intruct;
            intruct.push_back(intructor()); //Push back new subject created with default constructor.

            for(int lineNum = 0; lineNum>= lineCount; lineNum++) //Will create a set of vectors for each line.
            {
                intruct[lineNum].id = sTempToInt;
                intruct[lineNum].name = sTemp2;
                intruct[lineNum].dept = sTemp3;

                intruct.push_back(intructor());  //Adds a new element:
            }

            cout << sTempToInt << "\n" << sTemp2 << "\n" << sTemp3 << "\n";
        }
```

The part that is giving me the error is

```
vector<department> deptVec;
    cout << "Vector output: " << deptVec[0].budget;
```

It is suppose to output a int but throughs an error.
I checked that department.budget is holding the int. Not sure what to try.

Comment: In `vector<department> deptVec; cout << "Vector output: " << deptVec[0].budget;` How many elements are in the vector?

Comment: Post your `department` function please.

Comment: And why are you calling `.budget` on `deptVec`?

Comment: After the program runs, there are 3 elements in `deptVec[0]` and `deptVec` goes up to `deptVec[3]`. 3 elments per struct. Here is the department struct.

    `struct department {
    string dept;
    string building;
    int budget;
};`

Comment: @GKE i think that might be my problem, not sure where I came up with that or why.

Answer (score 0):

The deptVec vector is empty and you are trying to access an element from it. Try pushing values to deptVec before cout.

Comment: Aren't they already pushed if I can see the variables listed and established in the vector? This is how the vector looks when I use a break right before the lines that break the program.

`depart std::__1::vector<department, std::__1::allocator<department> > size=5 

[0] department 
dept std::__1::string "BIOL" 
building std::__1::string "LEO" 
budget int 60000`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. For whatever reason, I was trying to create a new vector after the while loop instead of using the one being used in the while loop.

This is before:
        `vector<department> deptVec;
    cout << "Vector output: " << deptVec[0].budget;`

After(what it should be): `cout << "Vector output: " << depart[0].dept;`